# Não encontra o controller php com laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Olá pessoal estou começando com o laravel, já me deparei com um problema. Criei o controller, as rotas, mas mesmo assim, está me dando o seguinte erro:

Class App\Http\Controllers\Contato2Controller does not exist.

O que devo fazer malta? Já procurei na net, mas sem sucesso. Desde já, agradeço.

Para melhor compreensão, a seguir vai o código.

**Controller:**

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Contato2Controller.php extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function enviar(Request $request)
    {
        $contato = new Contato();
        $contato->nome = $request->get('nome');
        $contato->email = $request->get('email');
        $contato->mensagem = $request->get('mensagem');
        $contato->save();

        echo "Dados armazenados com sucesso! Código: " .$contato->id;
    }

    public function lista()
    {
        return view('lista', array('contatos'=>Contatos::all()));
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```html
Route::get('/','Contato2Controller@index');
Route::post('/enviar','Contato2Controller@enviar');
Route::get('/lista','Contato2Controller@lista');
```

**OBS:** Estou a usar a versão 5.1 do laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que as rotas estão corretas e a nomenclatura de nomes está de acordo com os padrões do laravel, o problema deve estar aqui:

```
class Contato2Controller.php extends Controller
{
...
```

sobrou um .php, então realmente não existe o controller Contato2Controller (existe apenas o Contato2Controller.php). Então resolvendo fica mais ou menos assim:

```
class Contato2Controller extends Controller
    {
    ...
```

O laravel tem uma ferramenta de linha de comando para fazer a geração automatica tanto do controller quanto da rota, chamada [artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan).

Comment: Nem é um problema de padrão do Laravel, o PHP de fato não reconhece pontos em nomes de classes, funções e namespaces. Isto na verdade emite algo como `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '{'`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já ia comentar, o mais estranho é que na própria pergunta isso não consta do problema.

Comment: @Edilson provavelmente o usuário é ou o Laravel emitiu aquele erro customizado sem detalhes (talvez o AP tenha desligado o modo debug sem querer)

Comment: Mas para exibir os erros de sintaxe citados acima o arquivo em questão deveria ser executado. Provavelmente o nome do arquivo não corresponde ao nome da classe.

Comment: Ok pessoal! Peguei todas as dicas dadas, criei outro controller (contato3Controller), copiei o código do controller anteior e colei neste. Aquele erro sumiiu, e surgiu outro: FatalErrorException in contato3Controller.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Contato' not found
Este erro ocorre quando tento gravar algo na bd.

Comment: Você não criou uma classe chamada Contato, na pasta model do laravel e não importou essa classe no controller Contato3Controller. Da uma olhada [neste](https://blog.butecopensource.org/tutorial-laravel-5/) e [neste](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart) guia de início.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Juven. Na verdade já tinha criado a classe, faltava apenas importa-la no controller. Fiiz isso e deu certo, está a funcionar. Valeu!